# WeChat error 50001 when trying to retrieve access token

Tags: rest, wechat

When trying to call "WeChat Official Account" api:

```
https://api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/token?grant_type=client_credential&appid=[APPID]&secret=[SECRET]
```

As a result I get:

```
{
   "errcode": 50001,
   "errmsg": "user unauthorized hint: [584DOa0572e578]"
}
```

I can see that I have permission to get access token:
[image]

I read somewhere, that the official account has to be verified for API access, but I cannot find it in official documentation.

Can anybody suggest a possible reason for error code?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Return_Codes

50001 error code means the user is not authorized to use that API

Comment: Thanks, but it says that in the error message. I'm trying to find out what I'm missing, that I'm not able to make this call.